# Track crypto wallets voting on certain platforms

Tags: cryptocurrency, metamask

Is there a way to track if a specific wallet has submitted proposals and/or joined the voting on governance proposals such as [snapshot](https://snapshot.org/#/), [uniswap](https://app.uniswap.org/#/vote) and similar governance proposal platforms? Is there an api to check past histories of these activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is!

For uniswap, you can call the getCurrentVotes and getPriorVotes methods on the [Uniswap token contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984#readContract) at the address.

The other projects using snapshot work similarly.

On similar governance platforms, similar methods probably exist on the governance token or on an other contract. However, their name and implementation might vary.